# Why vscode does not include ffmpeg in its build?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create extension that enables video plays in webview on vscode workbench.

I have already tried vid.canPlayType within Extension Development Host with various video formats, but none of them worked.

Some developer said it will work with another nw.js project [here](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/152#issuecomment-492050247), but I still cannot figured it out

Why Vscode team does not include default FFMPEG codes in the electron build ?

Comment: Most chromium builds don't include by default. Its almost always an addition. VSCode isn't primarily a video player so to reduce build size and lower complication, not exactly a surprising choice by them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS Code does not include ffmpeg because there is currently not a good use case to ship it with an editor. ffmpeg also has a cost in terms of executable size, security surface, and all the fun around patent/license stuff.

As of VS Code 1.38, there are no plans to change this. You should investigate alternative ways to present this media, such as opening it in the user's normal browser

*Source: I'm a developer on VS Code and created the webview api*

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg support has been added in the [Aug 2022 release](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71) of vscode